# Jquery: does Jquery have a green 'checkmark' box like the Highlight / Error boxes

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

When looking at Jquery you can find 2 css style boxes. One containing Highlight (yellowish) and the other is Error (red)

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Now i was wondering if there also is a green box of this with a checkmark or something.
This can be very handy if you want to give a notice if something is approved

does anyone know if this feature is there and also how to reach it?

thanks
matthy

Answer (score 1):

At the themeroller link you provided there's a set of framework icons, containing this one:

```
.ui-icon-check
```

Perhaps you can use that in your themes?

Edit: If you also need actual functionality to generate the "check" for input fields you probably want to look for client side validation stuff. I don't know of any links for that but surely someone else will.